Experiment to determine friction coefficient
I've come up with an experiment to determine the dynamic friction coefficient of two bodies made up of arbitrary materials, and I'd like to know whether it is good enough or if it needs polishing (which it surely will). Let a body made of a given material be cast with some initial velocity on a surface made of some other material, until it comes to a full stop. Then, all the work done by the friction force of the floor on the body would have turned into heat, which would mostly be absorbed by the body itself and not by the medium (i.e: air). Mathematically:
$$W=F\Delta x =\mu m g\Delta x = c_Vm\Delta T$$
Measuring the distance the particle has travelled, as well as the temperature of the body before and after the experiment, we could easily determine the friction coefficient of the system:
$$\mu = \frac{c_V}{g}\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta x}$$

Why would you assume all of the heat goes into the stopping object? Some of the heat will surely go into the floor. If you look at IR film of cars or bikes stopping the ground absolutely has a bright streak (I've done this is a teaching demo many times).

@mike1994 thanks for your response! I thought the heat that went to the floor would actually be given by the friction force the object exerts on the floor (Newton's 3rd law) just as the heat that goes to the object is given by the friction force exerted by the floor on the object

Have you done any order of magnitude calculations to ascertain the order of magnitude of the temperature change?

@Lagrangiano definitely not in this case! If you have an adiabatic situation, you can make arguments ~similar~ to Newton's 3rd law, but we are definitely generating heat from macroscopic mechanical energy here. How much heat is going to go into the object vs. the floor is going to depend on the thermal conductivity of both, and how "vast" the floor is compared to the obejct.

The heat would be distributed between the sliding object and the object is is sliding on. The easiest way would be to measure the initial velocity of the object and the time to stop and just compute its deceleration trought $\frac{v_0}{\mathrm{t}}$.

There are a number of issues regarding your experiment.

Probably the biggest issue is the assumption that all the energy dissipated by friction is absorbed by the sliding object and none in the surface.

Having run temperature tests on literally hundreds of products during my career as a test engineer, I can tell you that the number of temperature measurements, their locations, and the measurement procedure can effect the $\Delta T$ measured and its significance.

Then there is confidence in the value you use for the specific heat of the material.


I suspect you can get a more accurate estimate of the friction coefficient if you simply use the work energy theorem which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Since in your example the only force doing work on the object is the friction force, call it $f$, then per the work energy theorem,
$$fd=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
where $f$ is the average kinetic friction force, $d$ is the distance the object travels, and $v$ is the initial velocity of the object.
Although measuring the initial velocity may be difficult and involve some degree of inaccuracy, I suspect it would give more accurate results than the potential errors associated with (1), (2) and (3) above.
But the only way to really find out, is to do the experiment both ways on objects constructed of materials for which there are published values of the coefficient of dynamic friction.
Hope this helps.
